# Determinant of a checkerboard Hankel matrix with Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants, catalan-numbers, hankel-matrices

My goal is to compute

\begin{equation}
I =  \det \left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}\right)
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $n \times n$ checkerboard matrix filled with Catalan numbers:
$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{crc}
    \mathbf{A}_{ij}  = C_{p-1} \alpha^{2(p-1)} &\mbox{ if }& i+j=2p \mbox{, and with }C_p= \frac{1}{p+1}\binom {2p} {p}\\
    \mathbf{A}_{ij}  =  0 &\mbox{ if }& i+j \mbox{ is odd.}
   \end{array}
\right.
$$
with $\alpha >0$ a parameter.

Numerically, it seems that $I$ has a limit when $n\to +\infty$ if $\alpha<1/2$ and diverges to $\infty$ otherwise.

Any idea ?

Comment: What are the first few values? Anything in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: what relation does $p$ have to $n$?

Comment: @Suvrit :p is just (i+j)/2 when i+j is even

Comment: @DouglasZare : if $\alpha=1$, then the first values are 2, 6, 24, 160, 1640, ...Nothing found in OEIS.

Comment: Maybe some ideas in http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~omer/DOWNLOADABLE/catalan_hankel09.pdf may be helpful.

or also in: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.3044.pdf

Comment: Note that there is no interaction between the even and odd coordinates in your matrix. In other words, if you rearrange rows and columns to put the even-numbered rows first and then the odd-numbered ones, you get a block-diagonal matrix and you should probably be looking at the blocks individually. It's also unclear at what numbers your matrix starts, you should write down the top left corner explicitly. There's a nice combinatorial interpretation for these; see http://jacobi.math.wvu.edu/~jerzy/research/21catalan.pdf.

Comment: Is the condition  on $\alpha$ equivalent to saying that the spectral radius is smaller than $1?$

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Thanks for this nice comment.

Comment: As a power series in $\alpha$, the first few coefficients only depend on finitely many entries and are effectively computable. If you want to understand the limit, that is what I would OEIS.

Answer (score 5):

If you consider the operator on functions that sends $f(x)$ to

$$Tf(y) = \int_{-2}^2 \frac{ \sqrt{4-x^2} }{2\pi } \frac{1}{ 1- \alpha x y} f(\alpha x)  dx$$

then this is a well-defined integral operator from functions on $[-2\alpha,2\alpha]$ to functions on $[-2\alpha, 2\alpha]$ as long as $\alpha<1/2$.

Moreover, if $f(x)=x^{i-1}$, then the coefficient of $y^{j-1}$ in $Tf(y)$ is exactly $\mathbf A_{ij}$. So the limit of your determinant should be exactly the Fredholm determinant of this integral operator.

I'm not sure if this helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\binom{2p}{p} =O\left(\frac{4^p}{\sqrt{p}}\right),$$ the coefficients of your matrix are unbounded when $\alpha > 1/2,$ while for $\alpha < 1/2$ the matrix $A$ is well-approximated by its piece where $i+j$ is small, so your observations are not surprising. The interesting case is $\alpha = 1/2,$ where I have no intuition.

**EDIT** A mathematica experiment seems to indicate that the determinants converge slowly for $\alpha = 1/2.$

Comment: Thank you! Just a minor comment : the fact that the coefficient are unbounded does not imply that the determinant will be large, I think.

Comment: @user16215 It does not logically imply it, it suggests it - notice that I never claimed that this was proof.